# Nette PHP framework and RESTful API with token authentication

Tags: javascript, php, rest, nette

Is Nette PHP framework is suitable for creation of RESTful API in PHP (for client JavaScript application), I cannot find a proper documentation apart `IAuthenticator`

- Does Nette offer support RESTful? If no, does exist some **stable**
  "extensions"?
- Does Nette offer support for token authentication? I
  notice cookies is the default using `SimpleAuthetication`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used [drahak/Restful](https://github.com/drahak/Restful) long time ago. Last commit was 2 months ago so you should not have any problems. It provides you with more advanced router, OAuth2 and another tools to help you with building your API.

```
$router[] = new CrudRoute('api/v1/<presenter>/<id>/[<relation>[/<relationId>]]', 'Articles');
```

Also there was workshop on [#posobota](http://posobota.cz). Sources from API workshop can be found in [fprochazka/workshop-rest-api-sandbox](https://github.com/fprochazka/workshop-rest-api-sandbox) repository on GitHub.

Let me know if it works fine for you!

Comment: I would suggest adding a regexp specifier for the parameter value. Like this `'api/v1/<presenter>/<id \d+>/[<relation>[/<relationId \d+>]]'` if you have integer ids.

Comment: @FilipProcházka it is example from package I have mentioned. Send PR to doc to help its users.

Answer (score 3):

I am currently using [Nette-RestRoute](https://github.com/newPOPE/Nette-RestRoute). Taken from description it "Automatically maps REST actions to Presenters and actions in the defined module." Usage is pretty straightforward so I would recommend it.

Comment: drahak/Restful offers you more options, but for simple apis I would also suffest Nette-RestRoute. I used it right now for internal communication between apps and it works just fine :)